# How to mimic range and chart activity using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, range

The basic data set looks like this:

FIG 1
[image: data set]

What a pre-decessor did with the data set is to make it linear by copying all the data, i.e. saturday -> data, sunday -> data

Like this:

FIG 2
[image: data set two]

Using this format, he was able to generate a graph like this:

FIG 3
[image: final output graph]

Now, I have started to automate this document, where now, I have got to the stage of automating Fig 1.

My question is, by looking at the graph, is there a way to skip FIG 2 and just generate the graph using the data in FIG 1?

I have spent a couple of hours thinking about this and I cant seem to think of a solution.

I was thinking along the lines of creating a data range with, 00:00, 01:00 ..... and the day data, iterating that for all the days then combining the range to make a mega  range, but I can't see how that will work.

Can anyone push me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: i've just tried to think about the process logically, I wanted to post on here to maybe get a better solution, rather than just copying the data sets and to fit the format of FIG 2. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of would be to write some vba which creates the fig 1 format from the original format.  I'm fairly certain Excel doesn't allow you to draw the chart you want from the data in the original format but the vba should be quite simple.

For readability I'd recommend you transpose the fig 2 data so that it is going down rather than up.  The vba should traverse the data and write the chart data rows, then update the chart data source to use your finished range.

That's assuming the number of periods will be changing.  If they won't you can just use formulae to rearrange the data and no vba will be required.